# How-to conform to a max/min width/height

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave (https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave). I need to make sure images conform to a maximum/minimum height and
width? Otherwise an error should display.

Should this be handled in the uploader class or in the model (possibly
through a custom validation method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate image width/height on the client side, but that does not guarantee anything, because it's easy to manipulate/circumvent.

For user friendliness: check on the client side and give a warning before uploading. For data integrity, check on the server side after upload.

Comment: I know about client side. So validating min/max width/height can only be done after image is uploaded? Can't be done before or during?

Comment: You can't do anything server side *before* uploading. You don't have an image. You might be able to extract some data from the image header, but that might be quite complex to achieve, because you have to hack into Rack (which is handling the actual file upload).